# Adding same model to panel heading and footer

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

I want to add same variable to ng-model in panel-heading and panel-footer. If panel-heading is clicked, panel-footer should be disabled. Since the scope is different, variable in panel-footer remains undefined even after updating variable in panel-heading.

```
    <div class="panel-heading" style="height: 45px; position: relative; float: left; width: 100%">
    <div class="row" style="padding: 0px 5px;">
        <div class="col-md-11" style="display: inline-flex;">
            <input type="checkbox" title="Accept" ng-model="isButtonDisabled" ng-click="disableFooter();isButtonDisabled=true">         
        </div>      
    </div>
</div>

 <div class="panel-footer" style="padding: 5px;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">         
            <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" ng-model="isButtonDisabled" ng-disabled="isButtonDisabled">
                <span ng-show="isButtonDisabled">Disabled</span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please help! I am new to AngularJs.

Answer (score 0):

add ng-controller="yourController" inside your div blocks

```
<div class="panel-heading" ng-controller="yourController">
....
</div>

<div class="panel-footer" ng-controller="yourController">
....
</div>
```